# How to bundle script with import statement with browserify

Tags: javascript, import, export, browserify

lets say I have a script that used a node_module import such as

`import module from 'module';`

On the web browser with browserify? When I try to run browserify it says

`'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to first run it through babel/babelify.